# Publishing fails Sitecore Horizon

Tags: publishing, horizon

I'm working on `Sitecore 10.2` project, it's upgraded from the `8.2 version`.
`Horizon` is installed and I can open the content using it and the horizon index is being built without errors.

But when I try to publish an item, it fails and shows this message:

[image]

I checked the logs, but there are no exceptions, I checked the network tab and checked the API response:

```
{"data":{"publishItem":null},"errors":[{"message":"Error trying to resolve publishItem.","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["publishItem"],"extensions":{"code":"INVALID_OPERATION"}}]}
```

Comment: Did you try this using experience editor? if the publish works from there?

Comment: @SumitBhatia thanks for your answer, the issue was at the publishing targets configurations

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
I had two publishing targets, web01 and web02, one of them was not configured correctly, so this caused the issue.